# Can you prevent inherited private members being called through the parent at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

If you have a feature rich class, possibly one you do not own/control, it is often the case where you want to add some functionality so deriving makes sense.

Occasionally you want to subtract as well, that is disallow some part of the base interface.  The common idiom I have seen is to derive and make some member functions private and then not implement them.  As follows:

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual void foo() {}
  void goo() { this->foo(); }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
private:
   void foo();
};
```

someplace else:

```
Base * b= new Derived;
```

and yet another place:

```
b->foo();  // Any way to prevent this at compile time?
b->goo();  // or this?
```

It seems that if the compilation doesn't know that it is derived, the best you can do is not implement and have it fail at runtime.

The issue arises when you have a library, that you can't change, that takes a pointer to base, and you can implement some of the methods, but not all.  So part of the library is useful, but you run the risk of core dumping if you don't know at compile time which functions will call what.

To make it more difficult, others may inherit from you class and want to use the library, and they may add some of the functions you didn't.

Is there another way? in C++11? in C++14?

Comment: Why do you think this makes any sense? By deriving publicly, you tell the world `Derived` is a special kind of `Base`, and `Base` has `public foo` and `goo`, so `Derived` also will.

Comment: Can you give us an example of why you would want this?

Comment: Tl;dr, just derive `Derived` privately from `Base`

Comment: Please define who **should** and **should not** be able to call `foo()`.  For example, "derived classes should be able to call `foo()` but clients of `Base` should not."

Comment: @WorldSEnder That would disallow `Base * b= new Derived;`.

Comment: @juanchopanza, most likely closest to what he wants. The moment you can do `Base *b = new Derived;` you can also `b->foo()`

Comment: @WorldSEnder No, that's not what he wants. He wants something that can't be done.

Comment: "disallow some part of the base interface" The problem is that your design is broken. View public inheritance as a *"is a"* relation. The derived classes must at least have every feature all bases have. If this is not given, don't derive.

Comment: I don't think deriving from a class is a good way to add functionality. Just write a function. Inheritance is full of pitfalls. At a push, you can derive privately, and only expose a subset of the base's members.

Comment: After 2nd OP edit...  Just derive privately or use composition and expose the public operations you want.  Trying to do this via public inheritance is a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: _"Occasionally you want to subtract as well, that is disallow some part of the base interface"_ woah woah woah what????

Comment: read use case at bottom from last edit

Comment: *"takes a pointer to base, and you can implement some of the methods, but not all."* Do you really think this is a good idea? Do you really want to write code that might break with every little bugfix-update the library guy provides? Again, you promised him that he will always get a pointer to some kind of `Base`, with all its features! Better find a library more appropriate for your problem if you really cannot implement all required functions.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum There always exists the runtime option with `typeid()` and "reflection."

Comment: Ideally for your idea, the base class would have virtual methods that essentially ask if certain functionality is supported or not. Then you could override them to say "no" for the aspects you don't want to support. But otherwise if no such mechanism exists, then whoever designed the base had particular expectations and assumptions about any possible derived classes. There's no real way to subvert that without changing the base.

Comment: Your use case doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyze this, focused on two major points:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo() {} // This 1)
// ... 
class Derived : public Base // and this 2)
```

In 1) you tell the world that every object of `Base` offers the method `foo()` publicly. This implies that when I have `Base*b` I can call `b->foo()` - and `b->goo()`.

In 2) you tell the world that your class `Derived` publicly behaves like a `Base`. Thus the following is possible:

```
void call(Base *b) { b->foo(); }
int main() {
    Derived *b = new Derived();
    call(b);
    delete b;
}
```

Hopefully you see that there is no way `call(Base*)` can know if `b` is a derived and thus it can't possibly decide at compile-time if calling `foo` wouldn't be legal.

---

There are two ways to handle this:

- You could change the visibility of `foo()`. This is probably not what you want because other classes can derive from `Base` and someone wants to call `foo` afterall. Keep in mind that [virtual methods can be private](/q/3970279), so you should probably declare `Base` as

```
class Base
{
  virtual void foo() {}
public:
  void goo() { this->foo(); }
};
```

- You can change `Derived` so that it inherits either `protected` or `private` from `Base`. This implies that nobody/only inheriting classes can "see" that `Derived` is a `Base` and a call to `foo()`/`goo()` is not allowed:

```
class Derived : private Base
{
private:
    void foo() override;
    // Friends of this class can see the Base aspect
// .... OR
// public: // this way
    // void foo(); // would allow access to foo()
};
// Derived d; d.goo() // <-- illegal
// d.foo() // <-- illegal because `private Base` is invisible
```

You should generally go with the latter because it doesn't involve changing the interface of the `Base` class - the "real" utility.

---

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Deriving a class is a contract to provide *at least* that interface. Subtraction is *not* possible.

This seems to be what you want to do:

```
struct Library {
    int balance();
    virtual int giveth(); // overrideable
    int taketh(); // part of the library
};

/* compiled into the library's object code: */
int Library::balance() { return giveth() - taketh(); }

/* Back in header files */
// PSEUDO CODE
struct IHaveABadFeelingAboutThis : public Library {
    int giveth() override; // my implementation of this
    int taketh() = delete; // NO TAKE!
};
```

So that you can't call `taketh()` on an `IHaveABadFeelingAboutThis` even when it is cast as the base class.

```
int main() {
    IHaveABadFeelingAboutThis x;
    Library* lib = &x;
    lib->taketh(); // Compile error: NO TAKE CANDLE!
    // but how should this be handled?
    lib->balance();
}
```

If you want to present a *different* interface than the underlying library you need a facade to present *your* interface instead of the that of the library.

```
class Facade {
    struct LibraryImpl : public Library {
        int giveth() override;
    };
    LibraryImpl m_impl;

public:
    int balance() { return m_impl.balance(); }
    virtual int giveth() { return m_impl.giveth(); }
    // don't declare taketh
};

int main() {
    Facade f;
    int g = f.giveth();
    int t = f.taketh(); // compile error: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't think your overall situation is good design, and I share many of the sentiments in the comments, I can also appreciate that a lot of code you don't control is involved. I don't believe there is any compile time solution to your problem that has well defined behavior, but what is far preferable to making methods private and not implementing them is to implement the entire interface and simply make any methods you can't cope with throw an exception. This way at least the behavior is defined, and you can even do try/catch if you think you can recover from a library function needing interface you can't provide. Making the best of a bad situation, I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `class A:public B`, then you should follow the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

The Liskov substitution principle is that a pointer-to-A can be used as a pointer-to-B in all circumstances.  Any requirements that `B` has, `A` should satisfy.

This is tricky to pull off, and is one of the reasons why many consider OO-style inheritance far less useful than it looks.

Your `base` exposes a `virtual void foo()`.  The usual contract means that such a `foo` can be called, and if its preconditions are met, it will return.

If you derive from `base`, you cannot strengthen the preconditions, nor relax the postconditions.

On the other hand, if `base::foo()` was documented (and consumers of `base` supported) the possibility of it throwing an error (say, `method_does_not_exist`), then you could derive, and have your implementation throw that error.  Note that even if the contract says it could do this, in practice if this isn't tested consumers may not work.

Violating the Liskov substitution principle is a great way to have lots of bugs and unmaintainable code.  Only do it if you really, really need to.